# How do I use spaces and special characters in a radio_button's value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

There's this form in which the user select one of a few options. His answer will be displayed elsewhere, so it must be well formatted.

The thing is when you set the radio's value in Rails it also uses it for the `id` attribute, which will be invalid if I use spaces and other special characters.

See the example below:

```
<%= radio_button :a, "Yes, I want bananas." %>
<%= radio_button :a, "No, I rather have strawberries." %>
```

I would like this to be outputted as this:

```
<input type="radio" name="a" id="a_yes_i_want_bananas" value="Yes, I want bananas.">
<input type="radio" name="a" id="a_no_i_rather_have_strawberries" value="No, I rather have strawberries.">
```

I tried forcing a `value` option in the `radio_button` but it didn't work.

Any ideas ?

Update.

To make it clear, the user will only select one option. But my problem is:

The value you give when calling `form.radio_button` is used both as `id` and `value`. I want the `id` to be parameterized, but the `value` to keep its format - like uppercases and spaces.

I want the string "No, I rather have strawberries." to be submitted as it is, but the id to be "a_no_i_rather_have_strawberries".

Please tell me if it isn't clear yet. As you can see I'm not that good in english. =P

Another way to put that is:

I'd like to do this:

```
<%= radio_button :foo, "my_super_option", :value => "You are awesome! %>
```

But Rails ignores my `value` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got crazy or something. Rails magically begun to keep the `value` attribute with special characters and yet parameterized the `id` attribute.

This:

```
<%= f.radio :option, 'Hi! Would you like a coffe ?'%>
```

Became this:

```
<input type="radio" name="form_option" id="form_option_hi_would_you_like_coffee" value="Hi! Would you like a coffe ?">
```

Now everything works as expected. Sorry to trouble you folks and thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:a, "bananas") %>
  <%= label_tag(:a_bananas, "Yes, I want bananas.") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:a, "strawberries") %>
  <%= label_tag(:a_strawberries, "No, I rather have strawberries.") %>
```

Comment: The problem isn't the label, the input `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I think your last code example doesn't work because the first string parameter is the value, so the value in the options hash is ignored.

Have you tried specifying the id as part of the options hash?

```
<%= radio_button :a, "Yes, I want bananas.", id: "yes_i_want_bananas" %>
<%= radio_button :a, "No, I rather have strawberries", id: "no_i_rather_have_strawberries" %>
```

Comment: The problem with providing the ID manually is that we skip the magic Rails does when generating it automagically, prepending the object name and stuff like that. It's even worse when it's a nested object with index. :/

Comment: What happens if, in your original example, you use `radio_button_tag` instead of `radio_button`: `radio_button_tag :a, "Yes, I want bananas"`. Does this generate what you want, minus the label? Or does it munge the `value` in that case as well?

Comment: I don't really know, but it would be bad since outside the FormBuilder object I'd have to prepend the model name myself. Like `option_a` to `form[my_model][option_a]`.

Answer (score 0):

This actuallly looks like the choice of an input. you should probably use checkboxes for this:

```
<%= f.checkbox :flavor, "strawberry" %>
<%= f.checkbox :flavor, "bananas" %>
```

a radio button is meant for one selection out of a several options, what your example suggests is that you need to mark a single selection.

you can always use radio buttons but give them specific values like "strawberries" and "bananas" - and use your explanatory text in the label.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. The user will select only one option. The thing is I want the radio's value to keep uppercases, spaces and etc.